# Where is stddef.h defined in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

If I want to find the values of `stddef.h`, where is it defined? The `/usr/include/linux/stddef.h` almost has nothing,

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
#ifndef __always_inline
#define __always_inline __inline__
#endif
```

Specifically, I wanted to see how `size_t` is defined?

*Coming back to this very same question months later wanting to know how `whcar_t` is defined.*

Note, the internal `stddef.h` file has the typedef's for ,

- `ptrdiff_t`
- `max_align_t`
- `size_t`
- `wchar_t`

Comment: You should ask a new question (and if someone's diligent about it), presumably get a new answer (no cut/paste, self-references, etc).  `wchar_t` type is in stddef.h, but all of its **usage** is in wchar.h

Comment: @ThomasDickey I think they would be duplicates. gcc's stddef.h defines size_t, wchar_t, ptrdiff_t and max_align_t. I don't think we need a question though to tell me how to get GCC to dump the typedef for each one of them. They're all dumped the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard does not distinguish compiler features from library features. The distinction is an implementation detail and can vary from platform to platform, but there are common trends. For example the size of basic integer types such as `size_t` and associated macros such as `CHAR_BIT` and `SIZE_MAX` are properties of the compiler and compiler options; on the other hand the contents of `stdio.h` are usually independent of the compiler but dependent on how the standard library implements files.

`stddef.h` mostly declares compiler things, so it comes with the compiler. You'd better get different definitions if compiling in 32-bit or 64-bit mode, for instance, and you'll get different definitions with e.g. GCC and Clang. So look for it in compiler directories. Some compilers even don't have a disk file at all, they just treat the name `<stddef.h>` specially, but with GCC and Clang you do get a disk file.

You can find all the copies on your system with the `locate` command.

If you want to know [what include path GCC is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories) when given particular options, pass the option `-v` on the command line in additions to the other options you use in your build (especially `-m`).

If you just want this information without compiling anything, invoke GCC in preprocessor-only mode with empty input (`-xc -E /dev/null`; you need a `-xc` to specify the language is c because GCC can't tell what language you're compiling without a file name).

The same options work with Clang, by the way.

```
gcc -v -xc -E /dev/null 2>&1 |
awk ' /^End of search list/ {exit} p {print} /^#include <\.\.\.> search starts here:/ {p=1}' |
xargs sh -c 'for x; do if [ -e "$x/stddef.h" ]; then echo "$x/stddef.h"; exit; fi; done' sh
```

If all you want to know is the definition of `size_t`, then you don't need to know where it comes from. Ask the compiler to print the output of the preprocessor.

```
echo '#include <stddef.h>' | gcc -xc -E - | grep size_t
```

From `man gcc`,

> - `-E`  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.  The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output. Input files that don't require preprocessing are ignored.
> - `-x language` Specify explicitly the language for the following input files (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix).  This option applies to all following input files until the next `-x` option.

Comment: Thanks for the command to ask the compiler what it uses!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `-H` flag when you compile your source code and examine the output, you'll see the location of `stddef.h`, e.g.

```
gcc file.c -H
```

Answer (score -1):

`size_t` is defined in `/usr/include/sys/types.h`

Note that you may need to follow #includes from that file to find the real definition.

`stddef.h` is just a meta include file and the only unique definition in that file is the `offsetof` macro.